# DirectShow RenderStream successful, but no video

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directshow

I'm using the preview pin (PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW) on RenderStream to display the video of a webcam, but even though the function returns 0x1, the video window that pops up is empty. I can see the webcam turning on (LED turned green), but there's no image. This is the same with a capture pin, where the buffer never gets filled.

Interestingly, the program works fine for webcams built into laptops. I've tested with two separate laptops and both worked fine. The webcam itself is fully functional as I'm able to play video using Skype or MATLAB.

Does anyone have a clue to what may be happening here?

Comment: What if you build a capture/preview graph in Graphedit, does it work out? Did you check if your app filter graph is of a topology you expect, without third party filters?

Comment: It works on GraphEdit. The topology on GraphEdit is: Capture Source (capture filter) --> AVI Decompressor (added automatically) --> VMR9 Renderer.

But when I code it out, no video comes through...
The code uses RenderStream to connect the capture filter directly with VMR9